# Генерация XML и ошибка 502

Tags: php, xml, modx

Добрый день, на сайте под управлением cms MODx revolution должен генерироваться YML.xml файл для яндекс-маркета. Но при попытках его генерировать приходит ошибка 502. Я ограничил количество товаров для которых генерируется xml файл и всё заработало, так, по частям, я создал один файл, но заказчику нужно, что бы этот файл генерировался автоматически просто при заходе на страницу, так как данные товаров могут меняться и т.д. Возможно ли как то исправить эту проблему?

Comment: Да,безусловно это возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Хочешь чтобы хватало память на выгрузку? Сделай как Безумкин - выводи текстовые строки. Вот тебе [статья по этому поводу](https://bezumkin.ru/modx/minishop2/solutions/1401/), вот тебе [код для примера](https://gist.github.com/bezumkin/5829891).

**UPD:** 
Твой медленный код:

```
<?php
$SQLtxt = 'SELECT id FROM modx_site_content WHERE template = 1'; 
$q = $modx->prepare($SQLtxt); 
$q->execute(); 
$resultID = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
$count = count($resultID); 
foreach ($resultID as &$rowID) { 
    $resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $rowID['id']); 
    $yml .= '<offer id="'.$rowID['id'].'" type="vendor.model" available="'.htmlentities($resource->getTVValue('available'), ENT_XML1).'">'; 
    $yml .= '</offer>'; 
}
```

Вся быстрота `q->fetchAll` полностью нивелируется `$modx->getObject` и `$resource->getTVValue`. Вот как это делается быстро и "modx-way":

```
<?php
// выполняем всё за одни запрос
$q = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
// присоединяем тв к запросу
$q->innerJoin('modTemplateVarResource','TemplateVarResources'); // #1
$q->innerJoin('modTemplateVar','TemplateVar','TemplateVarResources.tmplvarid = TemplateVar.id'); // #2
// фильтруем
$q->where(array(
    'TemplateVar.name' => 'available', // имя tv поля // #3
    'modResource.template' => 1 // шаблон
));
// берем только нужные поля
$q->select('`modResource`.`id` as `id`');
$q->select('`TemplateVarResources`.`value` as `tv_value`'); // #4
// если данные есть - тогда выводим
if ($q->prepare() && $q->stmt->execute()){
    $resources = $q->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($resources as $resource) { 
        $yml .= '<offer id="'.$resource['id'].'" type="vendor.model" available="'.htmlentities($resource['tv_value'], ENT_XML1).'">'; 
        $yml .= '</offer>'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже что то подобное пытаюсь писать.

Comment: Вывожу текстовые строки, хотя используется для товаров не minishop, товары хранятся как ресурсы. Увы это не помогает 3700 товаров, цикл работает слишком долго.

Comment: Наверняка ты используешь вовсю getCollection вместо `$q->prepare() && $q->stmt->execute()` - посмотри внимательно на код Безумкина, там всё работает очень быстро именно изза вот этого момента.

Comment: `$SQLtxt = 'SELECT id FROM modx_site_content WHERE template = 1';
$q = $modx->prepare($SQLtxt);
$q->execute();
$resultID = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = count($resultID);
foreach ($resultID as &$rowID) {
    $resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $rowID['id']);
    $yml .= '<offer id="'.$rowID['id'].'" type="vendor.model" available="'.htmlentities($resource->getTVValue('available'), ENT_XML1).'">';
    
    $yml .= '</offer>';
}`



Вот та часть кода где обрабатываются товары. Самая большая проблема тут это цикл, запросы сильно на время не влияют тут.

Comment: Всё замечательно, ты получаешь список айдишников по-быстрому способу через `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC`, и тут же... `$resource = $modx->getObject('modResource', $rowID['id']); ` - всё портишь офигенно медленным запросом... Сейчас распишу в своём ответе как надо поступать правильно.

Comment: Да это намного быстрее, спасибо. Только вопрос один возможно как то получить несколько тв параметров а не фильтровать по 1му. Там их много будет. Я пробую пока добавить в селекте выборку id и name. Или мб попробовать фильтровать по всем нужным тв. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Убери строчки которые я пометил в коде ответа (#1-4) и вместо них для каждой из твшек пиши такое: `$q->innerJoin('modTemplateVarResource', 'tv', array('msProduct.id = tv.contentid', 'tv.tmplvarid = 21')); $q->select(array('`tv`.`value` as `tv_1`'));`, здесь `21` - айдишник твшки, а `tv_1` - любое имя чтобы не перепутать, после в массиве полученном просто обращайся по этому имени - $resource['tv_1']

Comment: Кажется почти всё, только ещё один вопрос возник, пытался получить таким способом заголовок и контент родительского ресурса для товара, но запрос нечего не возвращает. Писал так:

`$q = $modx->newQuery('modResource');
...
тут подключаются тв с помощью leftJoin с ними всё в порядке
...
$q->leftJoin('modResource', 'Parent', 'Parent.id = modResource.parent');`

и потом select. Пробовал ещё с помощью класса modDocument, тоже не работает. Где я ошибаюсь?

Пока сделал с помощью Get вроде всё работает. Спасибо большое за помощь! Но если есть вариант улучшить, то лучше переделаю потом.

Comment: `$q->innerJoin('modResource','Parent','Parent.id = modResource.parent'); $q->select('\`Parent\`.\`id\` as \`parent_id\`');` - должно работать.

Comment: Не работает почему то.

Answer (score 0):

У вас либо физически не хватает ресурсов (память, процессор, места на диске), либо идут программные ограничения - настройки php, apache, nginx, mysql и т.д., либо есть какая-то проблема в скрипте экспорта. Что конкретно происходит - надо отслеживать по логам.

С учетом того, что на меньшей выборке товаров экспорт происходит нормально - я бы в первую очередь обратил внимание на физические параметры - память, и затем на настройки сервера - всякие лимиты на выполнение скриптов, доступную память, кэширование, буферы и т.д.

Comment: Правильная работа на меньшей выборке чаще всего говорит о том, что алгоритм выбран неоптимальный. Поэтому лучше сначала провести профилирование, найти узкие места в коде, оптимизировать его, а уж если не получится только тогда увеличивать лимиты и мощности

Answer (score 0):

Шаман-админ поведал что сервер получил некорректное сообщение от шлюза.
Решить можно так же написав небольшую обёртку - вместо генерации файла из 150 элементов, разбивай коллекцию на 10, генерируй для каждого и потом слей в один.
Заказчику явно фиолетово как оно будет, а ресурсов потреблятся может меньше.

Comment: Вместо обертки в первую очередь стоит код посмотреть и оптимизировать его по возможности. А уж если после всего все равно упираемся в ресурсы, то тогда можно и альтернативные решения вроде этого использовать

Comment: Оптимизация - это обязательно.  
Но т.к. я не могу оптимизировать код, то предложил что точно сработает, по данным ТС'а.

Comment: Ну так ТС может подумать, что это единственный вариант (без изменения параметров сервера). То, что "обязательно" для вас, для других может быть далеко не очевидным )) К тому же ваш вариант именно в таком виде скорее всего даст такой же результат - скрипт будет выполняться так же долго, что приведет к 502 ошибке. Поэтому кроме обертки стоило указать на необходимость выполнения данной операции в фоне и после генерации файла оповещение о результатах работы.

Comment: Про параметры сервера вроде оратор выше (или ниже, смотря как сортировать) ответил. Плюс - КАК именно реализовать предложенный мной алгоритм - это другой вопрос, я всего лишь дал идею решения (костыльную, правда).